# Фон для item android

Tags: android

Сделал xml разметку для фона item.xml, который будет пунктом списка. Вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" >
    <corners
        android:radius="100dp"
        />
    <gradient
        android:angle="45"
        android:startColor="#fff"
        android:endColor="#fff"
        android:type="linear"
        />
    <padding
        android:left="0dp"
        android:top="0dp"
        android:right="0dp"
        android:bottom="0dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Как теперь сделать на картинке чтобы было внутреннее свечение [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Что такое внутреннее свечение? Можно как то подробнее изложить ваши хотелки?

Comment: Это просто нарисовано. никакого "внутреннего свечения" на самом деле не существует.

Comment: Я понимаю что нарисовано. Я бы хотел узнать можно ли вообще через xml сделать синеватую такую же размытую рамку ?

Answer (score 1):

Говорят, можно сделать так:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <gradient
                android:angle="360"
                android:centerColor="#e95a22"
                android:endColor="#ff00b5"
                android:gradientRadius="360"
                android:startColor="#006386"
                android:type="sweep" />

            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#ff207d94" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="2dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="#fff" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Здесь цвета не такие как вы хотите, но это же не проблема так ведь?

[Оригинал здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20870853/android-shape-border-with-gradient)